# CSS - Scroll bar not working

Tags: html, css, angular, scrollbar

I created chatbox UI for my Application. I want to add scroll bar for the chatbox. I added the `overflow-y:auto;` in `chat-content` div class. But it doesn't work.If I add the style in `chat` div class it will work both messages and input box also. But I need scroll only messages. I don't know where to add the `overflow-y:auto;`
Any one please find the solution for me.
Here I attached the html  code for chatbox.

I followed this tutorial:
https://codepen.io/CodeFrogShow/pen/PKYvMo

html:

```
<div class="container_chatbot">
  <div class="app">
        <div class="head clearfix">
        <span class="messages-notification">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
            <span class="count"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="title">Messenger</span>
        <span class="create-new">
          <a (click) = "onVisible()" class="close">
            <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i>
          </a>

        </span>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="friend-list clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">
                        <span class="messages hide">
                        <span class="count"></span>
                        </span>
                        <img src="https://s5.postimg.org/3wnxyjz8n/image.png" alt="" />
                        <span class="name">
                             Jiffy

                        </span>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-messages">
                <div  class="chat">
                    <div  class="chat-content clearfix" >
                        <span *ngFor= "let message of messages_receiver" class="friend last">
                        {{message}}

                        </span>

                        <span *ngFor= "let message of messages_sender" class="you first">
                          {{message}}

                        </span>

                    </div>
                    <div class="msg-box">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "message" class="ip-msg" placeholder="type something.." />
                        <span class="btn-group">
                        <a (click) = "send()" >
                          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```